# Will the price for a B330 space station come down with volume?

Tags: bigelow, bigelow-expandable-module

I see sources quoting the [price for a Bigelow B330 space station at around 400M USD (with some interesting price analysis)](https://www.rocketstem.org/2014/03/12/city-in-the-sky-building-a-cheaper-space-station-with-bigelow-modules/). I have very little idea as to what goes into building these, and they have decades of research cost to recover, but if they go on to make hundreds of these, will the price come down? It seems very cheap as far as space stations go, but for a commercial company, this seems out of reach for most.

Comment: Sure. Unless the price gets inflated too :-)

Comment: Prices listed on a four-year-old article for hardware that existed in concept form only at that time.... sure, those prices seem legit.  Really detailed analysis too... </snark>

Answer (score 2):

Indubitably. The original research was done by NASA as the Transhab project, which Bigelow "bought". BA tweaked it but it doesn't look like a huge investment for Bigelow to recover, which Wikipedia puts at $250 mil so far - less than the price you quoted for a single B330.